# I wonder how computers that have been given private IPs from the same public IP communicate with each other

Tags: node.js, server, network-programming, client

I wonder how computers that have been given private IPs from the same public IP communicate with each other.

The server used Node.js and the private ip address it was granted is 172.30.6.191 and the client's private ip address is 172.30.7.191.

But why does not the ping go between the two computers?

I want to make the client connect to the server.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Via NAT. Off topic.

Comment: @Fortuneman Maybe try asking this on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), with a more thorough description of your network setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use NAT and the router remembers the source/destination ports to know where to route the traffic even though the IP is the same - that's for the traffic with the outside world. For the internal traffic between those hosts there is no need for the address translation because the traffic can be routed on the internal network, usually using private IP space.

See Wikipedia:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network